# How to get Vine video title/description?

Tags: php, api, video, twitter, vine

Here is a vine video example https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT. How can I get only it's description?

Let's say I have id of the video which is bjHh0zHdgZT and I need to get vine's description for my PHP based website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can parse the meta tag of the page ?

Source of vine page :

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="player">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Jethro Ames's post on Vine">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="SquareVine 1 #howto #favthings #loop">
```

To get the description from php with file_get_contents and preg_match :

```
<?php
    $url = "https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('~<\s*meta\s+property="(twitter:description)"\s+content="([^"]*)~i', $data, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
    if ( isset($matches[2]) ) {
       $description = $matches[2];
    }
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
 [0] => <meta property="twitter:description" content="SquareVine 1 #howto #favthings #loop
 [1] => twitter:description
 [2] => SquareVine 1 #howto #favthings #loop
)
```

Your description is $matches[2]. Be careful to control this content (html entities, sql escape, etc.)